# Is there an in memory messaging broker for functional testing of RabbitMq?

Tags: java, spring, testing, rabbitmq, functional-testing

I need to write functional tests flows that involve interaction with RabbitMq. But once the tests are run I will have to clear any existing message in the queue. Since RabbitMq is persistent I need some in memory substitute for RabbitMq. Just like the way we have HSQL for databases.

I have tried using `qpid` broker but with no luck.

I am using spring boot framework. So I just need to inject the bean of the inmemory queue instead of actual rabbit mq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/). Running a [RabbitMQ Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) in such a test is very easy. It will be restarted for every test class or method, depending on how you use it.

This will start a container running the `rabbitmq:3.7` Docker image for the test class.

```java
public class AmqpReceiveServiceIntegrationTest {

  @ClassRule
  public static GenericContainer rabbitmqContainer =
    new GenericContainer<>("rabbitmq:3.7").withExposedPorts(5672);

  static ConnectionFactory factory;
  static Connection connection;
  static Channel sendChannel;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(rabbitmqContainer.getContainerIpAddress());
    factory.setPort(rabbitmqContainer.getFirstMappedPort());

    connection = factory.newConnection();

    sendChannel = connection.createChannel();
    sendChannel.queueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);
  }

  @Test
  public void sendIsOk() {
    sendChannel.basicPublish("", "hello", null, "Hello World!.getBytes()); 

    // assertions ...
  }
}
```